# Multi Currency - When editing a currency field it shows the user currency in the input field instead of the record currency

Tags: sandbox, sales-cloud, multi-currency, currency

Multi Currency - When editing a currency field it shows the user currency in the input field instead of the record currency, but saves in the record currency anyway, so what is the point of the input field making it appear as if you are editing in the user currency? Users are being confused because they think they are entering in their currency, when they aren't.

In the first image, you can clearly see the record currency is in USD. It appears however that you are editing the opportunity value in GBP, but when you save, it saves the GBP amount you entered as USD.. SO what is the point of editing in GBP when it saves as USD? This is confusing our users. See the image below for proof that it saves in USD and not GBP
[image: Image before edit, shows GBP symbol instead of USD symbol, appears as if you are editing in GBP]

Here you can see, the value has saved as USD and not GBP... again, what is the point of showing GBP at all?
[image: Image after edit, value has saved in USD but it appears as if you are editing in GBP]

Comment: The field `Opportunity Value`  - is that the underlying `Opportunity.Amount` field? or some custom field?

Comment: That is the standard opportunity value field

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has confirmed that this is a bug. I was not going crazy after all. This seems like a pretty obvious bug - Not sure how this was missed during the QA.

Comment: was a known issue created or anything that could be shared?

Comment: Still not fixed for lightning-input-field as of Summer 22.....  Any idea when this will be fixed anyone?